# GreaseMonkey How to type text on google docs

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

Hi im using greasemonkey and i was woundering how i could make it type some "Hello This was an automated type". I want tried to do it on google docs but it wont work. This code that i have pasted down bellow worked on google.com

```
var input=document.createElement("input");
input.type="button";
input.value="Start.auto";
input.onclick = buttononclick;
input.setAttribute("style", "font-size:18px;position:absolute;top:120px;right:130px;");
document.body.appendChild(input); 

function buttononclick()
{
    if(window.location.href.indexOf("q=") < 0) //To avoid recursion
{
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for(var i=0;i<inputs.length;i++)
    {
        if(inputs[i].type == "text")
        {
            inputs[i].value = "AutoType";
        }
    }
    //Submit form
    document.forms[0].submit();
}
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by *on google docs* ...

Comment: i mean i want the script to type "Hello This is automated" On the google docs document.

Comment: what does your code do?

Comment: i want my code to be able to write "This is Automated" into a google docs file using greasemonkey. Now the code that i have shared with you guys will type "Autotype into google and submit it.